# Spark - build json payload for external data store

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, http

I have a spark job that needs to write to external data source using a REST api. The api accepts a json payload. What would be an efficient way of converting a bunch of rows to a json?

The jsons format should be something like this -

```
'{A: val1, B:val2,  C: val3 }
{A: val4, B:val5,  C: val6 }
{A: val7, B:val8,  C: val9 }'
```

Currently I am thinking of sending a payload foreachpartition

```
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sqlRDD.map((Function<Row, Row>) record -> { 
    ...   
    return RowFactory.create (col1, col2, col3);
}).foreachPartition( new MakeRestCall());


class MakeRestCall implements VoidFunction<Iterator<Row>> {
    @Override
    public void call(Iterator<Row> rowIterator) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sbPayload = new StringBuilder();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        sbPayload.append( gson.toJson(row));
    }
    // use http request to send the payload
    }
```

Would something like this work or are there any better ways of doing this?

Comment: You could probably add a `repartition` before the call to `foreachPartition` to adjust the number of partitions.